# Is quotient space a subspace of the underlying vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

If $W$ is a subspace of the finite dimensional vector space $V$,
is the quotient space $V/W$ a subspace of $V$ ? How do I prove or disprove this statement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $V$ is finite dimensional, so are $W$ and $V/W$. Thus, we have $V \cong k^n$ and $V/W \cong k^m$ with $m \leq n$, where $n=\text{dim}(V)$, $m=n-\text{dim}(W)$ and $k$ denotes the underlying field. It follows that
$$ V/W \cong k^m \hookrightarrow k^n \cong V.$$ Hence, $V/W$ may be regarded as a subspace of $V$.

However, in general, $V/W$ is not $\textbf{equal}$ to a subspace of $V$ since it is not even a subset of $V$.

Comment: Basically, I have completed Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, and I came across a section on quotient spaces  in the revised edition. I do not understand your answer and notation. I understand  that the quotient space has dimension $m$. Thereafter, could you simplify it a bit ?  Why isnt  $V/W$  a subspace of $V$. Isnt it a set of all cosets  v +W for v in V ? if so, shldnt a typical member  of V/W be in V ?

Comment: A typical element of $V/W$ is indeed a set of the form $v + W$ for some $v \in V$. Thus each element of $V/W$ is a subset of $V$ but is not an element of $V$.

Comment: @SheldonAxler   Professor Axler, am thrilled to get an answer from you! So if elements of vector subspaces are vectors, but  elements of the quotient space are subspaces themselves then what do we mean by dimension of the quotient space ? we define it for vector spaces only isnt it ?

Comment: Elements of the quotient space $V/W$ are not subspaces of $V$ but are (special) subsets of $V$. Addition and scalar multiplication are defined on $V/W$ in such a way that $V/W$ is a vector space, which is finite-dimensional if $V$ is finite-dimensional. See the section on quotient spaces in my book or other books for explanations of this.