# Embedding the quotient of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Q: Given a vector space $V$ over an arbitrary field and a linear subspace $W$, can we embed $V/W$ within $V$?

An embedding would be an injective morphism $i: V/W  \to V $ which is an isomorphism from the domain to its image?

Also are there similar results on groups and embeddings of the quotients by their normal subgroups?

---

In the case of finite-dimensional real or complex vector spaces, we can use orthogonality, but I am unsure how this would work otherwise.

Related question: [Is quotient space a subspace of the underlying vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519487/is-quotient-space-a-subspace-of-the-underlying-vector-space)

Comment: The last assertion is false: For general finite-dimensional real or complex vector spaces there is no notion of orthogonality---this requires additional data (e.g., an inner product or Hermitian product).

Comment: @Travis Is it not possible to define an inner/Hermitian product given a fixed basis and proceed from there?

Comment: Yes, it is always literally possible to find an embedding in your sense just by comparing dimensions, so this fact doesn't depend on $V/W$ being a quotient space in the first place. But in general there is no canonical injective map $V / W \hookrightarrow V$.

Comment: That said, in the quotient space setting, it is possible additionally to choose $i$ so that $\pi \circ i : V / W \to V / W$ is the identity map, where $\pi : V \to V / W$ is the canonical quotient map. But again, this does not determine a canonical choice $i$ except in the trivial case $W = \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO, let's back up. For groups or rings, there is no general guarantee that we can imbed a quotient into the group/ring itself. This is true exactly when the kernel has a compliment in the group/ring itself.

Vector spaces are special though. They can always be written as a direct sum of their one dimensional subspaces (with respect to a given ordered basis). So, in this case where we have (I will only demonstrate the finite dim. case but it is similar for infinite dim. at least with countable bases)

$$V=V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus \dots \oplus V_n$$

So, if we quotient out by a particular subpsace then we are just quotienting at by some ``subsum'' of the above essentially. That is, the kernel of that map (the thing you're quotienting out by) you have always has a compliment. That compliment is how we imbed $V/K$ into $V$. It takes very little work to show the isomorphism $V \cong K \oplus V/K$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Take a basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V/W$, and choose $f_i$ in $V$ such that $f_i$ maps to $e_i$ under the quotient map. The map from $V/W$ to $V$ linearly extending the above gives an embedding. If $\sum a_i e_i = z \in V/W$ (a finite sum) then the image in $V$ would be $\sum a_i f_i$. etc

Answer (score 3):

I completely agree with the previous answers. However, please be aware that any such an embedding is actually a choice! So there is no canonical way on doing it (it is only canonical if you quotient out a trivial space, i.e. the whole space or 0). Furthermore, if you are interested, this property is usually referred to as semi-simplicity of a category (something quite powerful).
and to get back to Rhythmink's answer: an example for rings or groups were this is not possible is the map $$\mathbb{Z} \to  \mathbb{Z}/(p).$$
I leave it to you to show that this admits no leftinverse ,i.e. an embedding 
$$\mathbb{Z}/(p) \to \mathbb{Z}.$$